# Stl container of std::basic_string type

Tags: c++, string, stl, queue

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int __cdecl main()
{   
    std::queue<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> results;

    results.push(TEXT("Hello world! ♥☻☺"));

    wcout<<results.front();
    delete [] results.front();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> Error 1   error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'void
>   *'    C:\Users\Tomek\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Solutions\clean_rough_draft\clean_rough_draft\main.cpp  20  1   clean_rough_draft

Why such error is being thrown and how to fix it?

Comment: [`#include <string>`](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/faq#toc1)

Comment: Why in the world are you doing `delete [] results.front();`?

Comment: What is the rest of the error message (which includes the actual template parameters)?

Comment: @SethCarnegie question updated

Comment: The error says you cannot `delete []` a `std::string`, and it's correct.  One normally deletes pointers, but you have no pointers in your code, there's nothing to clean up.  Why in the world are you doing `delete []` at all?

Comment: @Blastfurnace in order to free memory. Is it wrong approach?

Comment: You should use `results.pop()` to remove processed elements....

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74: Entirely. There's only one good place for `delete[]`, and that's inside the destructor of a class. In this case, that destructor is `std::queue<std::string>::~queue()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem was you forgot to include `<string>`.

Your current problem is your delete makes no sense.  Your string isn't dynamically allocated, and front() returns a reference to it anyway. So, you're trying to call array delete on something that isn't an array (a string is an object that encapsulates an array) and that wasn't dynamically allocated in the first place (and on a reference instead of a pointer).